# Jupyter imported module not using library

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I made an external module `model.py` and I want to import it within my Jupyter notebook.

```py
# model.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import chi2
from sklearn.covariance import EllipticEnvelope
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from scipy.stats import combine_pvalues

# ...

def predict(self, xtest):
        return np.where(self.predict_proba(xtest, False) < self.critical_value, 1., -1.)
```

When I try to call the `predict` method of my model class I get the error:
`NameError: name 'np' is not defined`.
I have the `numpy` library installed and I am strugggling to understand why it is not able to use it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you maybe have a file named 'numpy.py'?

Comment: Just to double check, you can import numpy normally in your Jupyter notebook, yes? It is possible to have numpy installed on a Python environment that is different from the one containing Jupyter